# How to print all the lines starting that matches a pattern using awk and save to a file?

Tags: awk

I have a file with 50,000 lines. I have to print all the lines starting with suppose

```
Dec 2 08:20:40 132.111.99.189 %ABC-5-896325: Built outbound UDP connection 1234567890 for outside:132.111.88.85/36 (132.111.88.85/36) to jump:132.111.99.56/12342 (132.111.99.56/12342)
```

using awk and then save it to test file. The number `12342` is different for different lines but the IP address would be same i.e. `132.111.99.56`
Also the time increases or decreases. suppose the example given above is 1000th line in that file.
I need to print those entire lines along with the time stamp and save it to a file. 
How could I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, do you need that particular timestamp or not? What is the real pattern you want to match?

Comment: Yes I need the time stamp. The pattern is Dec 2 08:20:40 132.111.99.189 %ABC-5-896325: Built outbound UDP connection 1234567890 for outside:132.111.88.85/36 (132.111.88.85/36) to jump:132.111.99.56/12342 (132.111.99.56/12342). But the time can change for different lines.

Comment: @pratik - It would be helpful (for yourself as well as others) if you could specify the **pattern** you want to use as the basis for selection.  You need to identify which parts are fixed, and which parts can vary, and how they can vary. I would suggest you read up on "regular expressions" (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) as they are used by awk and other tools to specify patterns.

Comment: FWIW - I have absolutely no clue what your requirements are. I suspect by the dearth of answers means that others are in the same boat. Follow the advice @glennjackman gave you in his comments and don't try to put formatted text in a comment - edit your question.

Comment: That's a job for `grep`

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. So was not knowing the format of asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
awk '/^Dec 12 08:22:22 %xyz-2-12345: pqrst/' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Were you thinking it would be more complicated than that?

Comment: I am sorry but even the number 12342 is different for different lines but the IP address would be same i.e. 132.111.99.56. Is that possible in awk to print such lines? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to fully describe the requirements. Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope i didn't make any mistake this time.

Comment: You need to show some sample input, and your desired output, making it clear which lines are to be discarded and which lines are to be kept.